# Spring MVC Validation Model

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc

I'm a noobie in Spring MVC

To make Spring MVC 3 Validation fully work,
Must it be that the Model Class (e.g. User class) to have a commandName as 'user'?

can't it be changed?

Whenever i change the commandName (e.g. 'userx'), the error messages in the JSP does not show.

Is it a prerequisite that the commandName must have a naming convention for its Class name?

I'm sorry if this question is already answered in the Spring Docs or here in stackoverflow, it seems that I can't find the answer myself. Thanks

EDIT: Here is my form
Command name is "searchClientForm", thus the corresponding Class name is SearchClientForm.java

```
    <form:form action="search.html"  commandName="searchClientForm" method="post" class="tabform">
        <h2>Client Maintenance</h2>
        <div class="spacer"></div>
        <div class="clear">
            <label class="error"><c:out value="${errorMessage}"/></label>
        </div>
        <div class="spacer"></div>
        <div class="clear">
            <label for="fieldCode">Filter: </label>
            <form:select path="fieldCode" items="${searchFields}" itemLabel="description" itemValue="key" id="fieldCode" />
            <label for="searchValue">Search: </label>
            <form:input path="search" id="searchValue" />
            <input type="submit" value="Go"/>
            <form:errors path="search" element="label" cssClass="error"/>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </form:form>
```

Comment: Can you paste the interesting parts of your JSP code (i.e. the form)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command name and class should be the same (command starts from lower case letter). You can extend the original class.
public class User extends SearchClientForm {} and place it in model as "user".

Comment: Thanks. it's clear to me now that there must be a naming convention. thank you